# Q:Android-How to detect collision from thread

Tags: java, android

I would like to be able to detect collision from a class which uses thread in my activity.When collision is detected, new activity should be started.In my case, new activity is started only when collision is detected and I touch the screen.I want it to immediately start new activity without me having to touch it.I think the problem is in update() method(in activity class).I'm calling it in the wrong place.Any suggestions?

Thread class

```
private boolean Collision;
Thread t=null;
Pravougaonik pr;
SurfaceHolder holder;
boolean isRunning=false;
SnakeParts sp;
ZmijicaCrtanje zc;
public ZmijicaSV(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder=getHolder();
    pr=new Pravougaonik(context);
    sp=new SnakeParts();
    zc=new ZmijicaCrtanje();
    Collision=false;
}

public void run()
{
    Paint p=new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
     while(isRunning)
     {

         if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
             continue;
         }
         Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();
         c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
         sp.Draw(c);
         pr.onDraw(c);
         sp.update();
         drawText(c);
         holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

         try {

            t.sleep(50);

         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}

public void resume()
{
    isRunning=true;
    t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void pause()
{
    isRunning=false;
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    t=null;

}

public void drawText(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(50);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("Score:"+zc.getScore(),getWidth()-230,getHeight()-25,paint);
}

public boolean checkCollision()
{
    if((sp.getHeadX()<-1)||(sp.getHeadX()>getWidth())||(sp.getHeadY()>getHeight())||(sp.getHeadY()<-1))
        Collision=true;
    return Collision;
}
```

}

Activity class

```
ZmijicaSV zmija;
private static int score=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    zmija=new ZmijicaSV(this);
    zmija.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(zmija);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zmija.pause();
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    zmija.resume();

}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean up=zmija.sp.isUp();
    boolean right=zmija.sp.isRight();
    boolean down=zmija.sp.isDown();
    boolean left=zmija.sp.isLeft();


    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if(up) {
                zmija.sp.setUp(false);
                zmija.sp.setRight(true);
                update();
                break;
            }

            if(right) {
                zmija.sp.setRight(false);
                zmija.sp.setDown(true);
                update();
                break;
            }

            if(down) {
                zmija.sp.setDown(false);
                zmija.sp.setLeft(true);
                update();
                break;
            }
            if(left) {
                zmija.sp.setLeft(false);
                zmija.sp.setUp(true);
                update();
            break;
        }


    }
        return true;
    }

public void update()
{
    score++;
    if(zmija.checkCollision())
        startActivity(new Intent(ZmijicaCrtanje.this, GameOver.class));
}
public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}
```

}